# Nuxt.js: how to track the value of $route.params.someKey?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js, I need to track the value of a `$route.params` 's key called `key1`.

`key1` values are calculated through `someFunction()`

How can I track `$route.params.key1` as a computed property?

The following does not work:

```
computed: {
   $route.params.key1: someFunction()
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to track the value, you should use a watcher, not a computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the value using computed properties.

```
computed: {
  key1() {
    return this.$route.params.key1
  }
}
```

But i think you want to do something when it has changed, then you'd use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers):

```
watch: {
  "$route.params.key1"(value) {
    track(value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Composition API (Nuxt 3 or Nuxt 2 Bridge) you can use `useRoute` instead of `$route` and the `watch` option on [`useAsyncData`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data#useasyncdata) / `useLazyAsyncData` / etc.

```js
const route = useRoute()
const { data: posts } = await useAsyncData(
  'posts',
  () => {},
  {
    watch: [route]
  }
)
```

In my case, on Nuxt 2 Bridge, this resulted in an infinite loop (`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`) and solved it with a workaround:

```js
const fetchSomething = () => {}

// This is a hack because `watch(route)` results in an infinite loop
const watchFlag = ref(true)
onMounted(() => {
  watchFlag.value = false
})

useLazyAsyncData('', () => {
  return fetchSomething()
})

watch(watchFlag, async () => {
  await fetchSomething()
})
```